# lang.hitch use in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder, dojo

Can someone explain `lang.hitch()` function use in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Comment: Do you want a demo code or just an explanation?

Comment: @Yogesh Chavan - A demo code would be great help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang"], function(lang){
   
    var myObj = { //A simple object with the property of foo
      foo: "bar"
    };
  
    var func = lang.hitch(myObj, function(){ //Using lang.hitch we can point to the scope that we want. Now "this" is pointing to myObj
      console.log(this.foo);//Grabbing the contents of foo that is in a different scope
    });
  
    func(); //Call the function printing out this.foo
  });
```

In the code above we have a simple `myObj` object with a property of `foo`. That object is in a different scope than the function below it. When we call our function called `func`, we add `lang.hitch` and specify the scope which is `myObj`. This allows us to grab the contents of foo even though it is in a different scope by calling `this.foo`.

If we did not have the `lang.hitch` we would get an error saying the `foo` was undefined.

For more info [dojo/_base/lang](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch)

Comment: As I understand, please correct if I am wrong, using lang.hitch() we can use object properties and functions in different scope or function.

Comment: Yes, that's the main use of the old dojo lang function. In new Code and using the new ArcGIS-JS-API4.x you do not need it anymore since you can use ES6 and array functions.

Comment: @Katah- Please can you provide link of any example to understand it for ArcGIS-JS-API4.x.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot format code in a comment. You can find information here: http://www.jsrocks.org/2014/10/arrow-functions-and-their-scope in the chapter "Scope"
Anyway, if you go to the Esri documentation https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/ you can find nice samples about that

Answer (score 2):

Robert Scheitlin answered a similar question on https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-web-appbuilder-questions/lang-hitch-what-does-it-do/m-p/436487

> lang.hitch enables you to keep a code block in scope. Say you have a
> function that has a inline function and you want to call this.map to
> get a refernec to the map object well if you are calling this.map from
> inside an inline function you are VERY like to see the error that
> this.map is undefined. Using lang.hitch before you call your inline
> function tell the inline function what 'this' is.
>
> https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html